# Biceps with dumbells-heavy lift

Tags: weightlifting, biceps

I am doing at least 16 kg dumbells. The problem is that my biceps isn't become bigger. I know it needs time but I don't know why now my biceps aren't become bigger. I will come to examples. When I was a starter after 2 months I see results. I was doing and more more and I make my biceps seem. What I want to say is that I didn't arrive to the great size it should have been and now I am trying it but nothing. I lift only heavy weights.

Comment: That's a nice story. You know that it takes time, but you want it to take less time. That's what most people want. Two months at the gym and looking like a greek god. But since this is a Q&A, I have a question for you: Is there an actual question from you?

Comment: Why do you think you should have arrived to "the great size", where did you read it? The issue with your program is that there is no progression. Try googling "strength program", maybe start with simple "5x5" program.

Comment: @aaaaaa This question (if you can even call it a question) is strictly about biceps though. What are you recommending, 5x5 bicep curls? On a more serious note, training with heavy weights isn't necessarily the right way to bigger biceps. The form is very important. Doing slow reps with lower weight while maintaining proper form and now swinging your shoulder / upper body is a lot more important than going up in weight.

Comment: @MJB its a bit off-topic, but i still want your perspective. As i understood stronglifts 5x5, you use barbell to develop strength and then can do isolation with much higher weights than you could before, which should help get bigger biceps faster.

Answer (score 1):

First, understand that growth occurs during the eccentric phase of an exercise.  This is simply when your muscle is contracting while lengthening *(so the load is greater than your muscles contraction force).*

---

Research also supports this. While looking at the effects of eccentric exercise on muscle growth it was found that:

> *Eccentric training performed at high intensities was shown to be more
>   effective in promoting increases in muscle mass measured as muscle
>   girth... eccentric exercise also resulted in the greatest
>   muscle cross-sectional area increases*

So this makes sense, if you're trying to lift something heavier than the force your muscle can produce - it has to adapt or grow to meet the imposed demands.

---

### Bicep Overload Example

This is the best exercise I've found.  End your "bicep" day with the following:

- Bring an adjustable bench over to the pull-up bar *(your using this
  to kick yourself back to the top after you reach the bottom)*
- Using an **underhand** grip, kick off the bench or jump up and Start with your chin at the top of the bar
- Resist your body weight from pulling you down *(but it will slowly)*
- Right before you get to the ground kick off the bench to go back to
  the starting position and repeat. *(Note you're kicking to get yourself backup not doing an actual chin-up)*

---

- Do this 5 times hold as long as you can - rest 30 sec - 1 min between
  sets. Essentially you're attempting to "curl" your body weight.
- This forces you to maximally contract your elbow (biceps) as your being lowered to the floor by gravity.

---

*Source:*
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18981046

Answer (score 0):

Do one exercise. Every training. 3 series - first warmup, next two as main training. Main series should take 8-12 reps. Weight should be set, to end main set, and not be able to do any more exercises. I would choose - [overhead cable curls](https://www.shapefit.com/exercise-guides/biceps-exercises-overhead-cable-curls.html). Other option is [cable curls](http://bodybuilding-wizard.com/standing-one-arm-cable-curl/). Doing till fall can be problematic, a specially if you are quite new to the training. Concentrate on technique, fall means that you can't do next rep keeping all things right. Use mirror to track if your body is waving. That are isolated exercises, so your body must be still. Usually elbows should also be still, for overhead curls you can move them a bit up at last part of exercise.

Other point is that if you train problematic group... do train, and eat carbs just after the training. Most people eat enough proteins, so you don't need to eat them. If you can't eat carbs just after - an hour later is also OK.

Do that for one month - then we can talk about results.